# Does each server (EC2 Node) behind a load balancer need their own SSL certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I have 2 EC2 nodes behind a load balancer. 
I need to setup SSL certificate for use with Amazon Web Services.
Does each server behind a load balancer need their own SSL certificate?
Or only the load balancer need the SSL certificate?

Comment: You can terminate the SSL certificate on the ELB :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **associate the SSL certificate with the load balancer**, and then use either normal HTTP between the Load Balancer and the server, or another form of authentication that is less resource-intensive than SSL.

See:

- [HTTPS Listeners for Your Classic Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-https-load-balancers.html)
- [HTTPS Listeners for Your Application Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html)

Comment: Is the traffic between the load balancer and node also encrypted or is it plain un-encrypted HTTP ?

Comment: You can also encrypt the data between the Load Balancer and the Amazon EC2 instances. This is done by configuring the web server on the EC2 instance to accept only certain Ciphers, which will then be negotiated with the Load Balancer. Some ciphers do not necessarily require certificates. (Sorry, I don't know any detail further than that -- hopefully somebody else will be able to comment.)

Comment: @KaranTikku In general you want HTTPS traffic terminated at the load balancer. Yes plain text HTTP does get sent to the backend instance but at that point you're in an isolated VPC. Also having to deal with HTTPS on the backend does create a CPU usage increase. You really only get into encrypting backend nodes when you're in high compliance area like no one should be seeing this patient's health data.